# memset and (&, >>) symbols in C

Tags: c, virtual-memory

I found one project where I can't uderstand one piece of code.[Virtual memory](https://github.com/rudyleiva93/Virtual-Memory-Manager)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TLB_SIZE 16
#define PAGE_SIZE 256
#define FRAME_SIZE 256
#define PHYSICAL_MEMORY_SIZE PAGE_SIZE *FRAME_SIZE

int logicalAddress = 0;
int offsetNumber = 0;
int pageNumber = 0;
int physicalAddress = 0;
int Frame = 0;
int Value = 0;
int Hit = 0;
int tlbIndex = 0;
int tlbSize = 0;

unsigned pageNumberMask = 65280;  // 1111111100000000
unsigned offsetMask = 255;        // 11111111

int tlbHitCount = 0;
float tlbHitRate = 0;
int addressCount = 0;
int pageFaultCount = 0;
float pageFaultRate = 0;

struct tlbTable {
  unsigned int pageNum;
  unsigned int frameNum;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Check to see if user inputs addresses.txt
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage ./VirtualMem_Manager <Filename.txt> \n");
    exit(1);
  }
  // Open addresses.txt, BACKING_STORE.bin, and
  // Create Output.txt to store program results
  FILE *addresses = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *BACKINGSTORE = fopen("BACKING_STORE.bin", "rb");
  FILE *Output = fopen("addressOutput.txt", "w");

  int physicalMemory[PHYSICAL_MEMORY_SIZE];
  char Buffer[256];
  int Index;

  // Declare and initialize pageTable[] array to -1
  int pageTable[PAGE_SIZE];
  memset(pageTable, -1, 256 * sizeof(int));

  // Declare and initialize tlb[] structure to -1
  struct tlbTable tlb[TLB_SIZE];
  memset(pageTable, -1, 16 * sizeof(char));

  // Read each address from addresses.txt
  while (fscanf(addresses, "%d", &logicalAddress) == 1) {
    addressCount++;

    // set the page number and offset for each logical address
    pageNumber = logicalAddress & pageNumberMask;
    pageNumber = pageNumber >> 8;
    offsetNumber = logicalAddress & offsetMask;
    Hit = -1;

    // Check to see if the page number is already in the tlb
    // If it is in tlb, then it is tlb hit
    for (Index = 0; Index < tlbSize; Index++) {
      if (tlb[Index].pageNum == pageNumber) {
        Hit = tlb[Index].frameNum;
        physicalAddress = Hit * 256 + offsetNumber;
      }
    }

    if (!(Hit == -1)) {
      tlbHitCount++;
    }
    // This "else if" loop is the tlb miss
    // Gets the physical page number from page table
    else if (pageTable[pageNumber] == -1) {
      fseek(BACKINGSTORE, pageNumber * 256, SEEK_SET);
      fread(Buffer, sizeof(char), 256, BACKINGSTORE);
      pageTable[pageNumber] = Frame;

      for (Index = 0; Index < 256; Index++) {
        physicalMemory[Frame * 256 + Index] = Buffer[Index];
      }
      pageFaultCount++;
      Frame++;

      // FIFO algorithm for the tlb
      if (tlbSize == 16) tlbSize--;

      for (tlbIndex = tlbSize; tlbIndex > 0; tlbIndex--) {
        tlb[tlbIndex].pageNum = tlb[tlbIndex - 1].pageNum;
        tlb[tlbIndex].frameNum = tlb[tlbIndex - 1].frameNum;
      }

      if (tlbSize <= 15) tlbSize++;

      tlb[0].pageNum = pageNumber;
      tlb[0].frameNum = pageTable[pageNumber];
      physicalAddress = pageTable[pageNumber] * 256 + offsetNumber;
    } else {
      physicalAddress = pageTable[pageNumber] * 256 + offsetNumber;
    }

    // Gets the value from the bin file provided
    Value = physicalMemory[physicalAddress];
    // print the addresses and value to Output.txt
    fprintf(Output, "Virtual Address: %d Physical Address: %d Value: %d \n",
            logicalAddress, physicalAddress, Value);
  }

  // The statistics of the program
  pageFaultRate = pageFaultCount * 1.0f / addressCount;
  tlbHitRate = tlbHitCount * 1.0f / addressCount;

  // Close files provided for the project
  fclose(addresses);
  fclose(BACKINGSTORE);

  // Print the statistics of the program to Output.txt
  fprintf(Output, "Number of Addresses: %d\n", addressCount);
  fprintf(Output, "Number of Page Faults: %d\n", pageFaultCount);
  fprintf(Output, "Page Fault Rate: %f\n", pageFaultRate);
  fprintf(Output, "TLB Hits: %d\n", tlbHitCount);
  fprintf(Output, "TLB Hit Rate %f\n", tlbHitRate);

  // Close Output.txt
  fclose(Output);

  return 0;
}
```

I can't understand these three lines.

```
pageNumber = logicalAddress & pageNumberMask;
pageNumber = pageNumber >> 8;
offsetNumber = logicalAddress & offsetMask;
```

As I understand papeNumber is value where logicalAddress and pageNuberMask a stored together. And this char & join them. Then we do offset on 8(>> 8).

And why is using memset dangerous.

Comment: `logicalAddress & pageNumberMask` will mask the upper 8 bit of the `logicalAddress` which corresponds to the page number, but this have to be shifted down by 8 bit by `pageNumber = pageNumber >> 8` to actually get the exact page number.

Comment: @Eraklon What keeps you from making an answer of that?

Comment: @Eraklon: The code seems to have some concept of frames, with pages being inside a frame. `logicalAddress & pageNumberMask` would then be intended to extract the page number bits, removing the frame bits above those, not to mask the “upper 8 bit” of the `logicalAddress`. If it were intended only to remove the lower 8 bits, taking just the upper 8 bits of 16, then the mask would be pointless, as the lower 8 bits would be removed by the shift. So the mask is needed to separate the page bits from the frame bits, not from the offset bits.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well I am almost never used memset so I cannot really answer that part. Also know just a little about virtual-memory. Although I googled memset dangerousness out of curiosity and kind of getting why it dangerous, but still others might know it better.

Comment: What's the question about "memset being dangerous"? It is not related to the other question at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil perhaps `logicalAddress` is 32 bits and the mask clears upper 16 bits as well.

Comment: Looking at the code further, it does seem like the physical address (output) gets frame bits beyond the page bits, but there is no use of bits in the logical address (input) beyond the page bits. The mask might just be intended to remove superfluous bits—either this simulation of virtual memory is ignoring those high bits because it is a limited student project or perhaps it is removing potential one bits created by sign-extension (or equivalent) somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Ayxan: It does clear the upper 16 (or more) bits as well; that is clear. The question is why.

Comment: `struct tlbTable tlb[TLB_SIZE];` followed by `memset(pageTable, -1, 16*sizeof(char));` looks like a bug. `pageTable` was initialized previously, and this was probably intended to initialize `tlb`. And the size is wrong; `tlb` has 16 elements (`TLB_SIZE` is 16), and each is several bytes. That line should probably be `memset(tlb, -1, sizeof tlb);`, and the previous `memset` should be `memset(pageTable, -1, sizeof pageTable);`.

Comment: Also: shifting right without masking is dangerous. Using signed types is not needed and also dangerous.

Comment: @wildplasser: The code does mask, in `logicalAddress & pageNumberMask`. That is exactly the code the question asked about!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(For purposes of illustration, this answer assumes the addresses are 32 bits, which appears to be consistent with the code in the question.)

```
pageNumber = logicalAddress & pageNumberMask;
pageNumber = pageNumber >> 8;
offsetNumber = logicalAddress & offsetMask;
```

The logical address is partitioned into three sets of bits: 16 upper bits that are ignored in this code, 8 bits used for a page number, and 8 lower bits that are used for an offset within a page.

`pageNumberMask` is a value that has been prepared to have 1s in the page number bits and 0s elsewhere. Then the operation `logicalAddress & pageNumberMask` performs a bitwise AND, which produces a value in which the only bits set are those that were set in the page number bits of `logicalAddress`. In other words, it produces a value in which the upper bits and the offset bits are cleared, effectively isolating the page number bits.

Then `pageNumber >> 8` shifts those page number bits down to the low bits, so the result is a page number. That page number can then be used to index arrays.

Similarly, `offsetMask` is a prepared value with 1s in the offset bits and 0s elsewhere, and `logicalAddress & offsetMask` extracts just the offset bits.

Note that `logicalAddress & pageNumberMask` serves a purpose only if bits above the page number bits might be set. This is because `pageNumber >> 8` removes the lower bits anyway, so there is no point in clearing them with an `&` operation. So this code separates the page number bits from the upper bits but makes no use of those upper bits. This might be because it is a simplified example for teaching, and actual code for deployment would make use of the upper bits.

> And why is using memset dangerous.

`memset` is a powerful routine that is easy to use incorrectly. Given incorrect arguments, it will modify any accessible memory, and the compiler often cannot detect that it has been used incorrectly, so it cannot provide a warning or error message.

### Defects in the Code

The code in the question has a number of defects, so it is not a great example for teaching:

- `struct tlbTable tlb[TLB_SIZE];` followed by `memset(pageTable, -1, 16*sizeof(char));` looks like a bug. `pageTable` was initialized previously, and this was probably intended to initialize `tlb`. And the size is wrong; `tlb` has 16 elements (`TLB_SIZE` is 16), and each is several bytes. That line should probably be `memset(tlb, -1, sizeof tlb);`, and the previous `memset` should be `memset(pageTable, -1, sizeof pageTable);`.
- Preprocessor macros are defined for various parameters, such as 256 for `PAGE_SIZE`, but then parts of the code ignore these and use hard-coded constants, as in `Frame*256 + Index`. This is a recipe for bugs.

Comment: Mhm, I read all the answers and decided to choose another project. Thanks a lot. You answer was useful.

Answer (score -1):

For performance and memory reasons `pageNumber` and offset in the `page` are stored in single `unsigned` value.

I will use `c++14` bit representation with `0b` prefix in comments to explain.

```
unsigned logicalAddress = someValue;           // <- 0bPPPPPPPPFFFFFFFF
```

where `P` denotes bits for `pageNumber` and `F` bits for `offsetNumber`;

```
pageNumber = logicalAddress & pageNumberMask;  // <- 0bPPPPPPPP00000000
pageNumber = pageNumber >> 8;                  // <-         0bPPPPPPPP
offsetNumber = logicalAddress & offsetMask;    // <-         0bFFFFFFFF
```

About `memset` using it is not dangerous if used correctly.